# How do we trace recursive algorithm in prolog?

Tags: recursion, prolog

I find it very unstraightforward, but I think I got the gist of it, please confirm whether I am in the wrong or not.

```
append([],L,L).
   append([H|T],L2,[H|L3])  :-  append(T,L2,L3).
```

Here's the query on the rule and the trace.

```
?-  append([a,b,c],[1,2,3],X) 

append([a,  b,  c],  [1,  2,  3],  _G518)
   append([b,  c],  [1,  2,  3],  _G587)
   append([c],  [1,  2,  3],  _G590)
   append([],  [1,  2,  3],  _G593)
   append([],  [1,  2,  3],  [1,  2,  3])
   append([c],  [1,  2,  3],  [c,  1,  2,  3])
   append([b,  c],  [1,  2,  3],  [b,  c,  1,  2,  3])
   append([a,  b,  c],  [1,  2,  3],  [a,  b,  c,  1,  2,  3])

   X  =  [a,  b,  c,  1,  2,  3]
   yes
```

append(T,L2,L3), "recurses" forward, diminishing the size of the list [H|T], and then append([H|T],L2,[H|L3]) "recurses" backward, increasing the size of the list L3. So, if I understand correctly, the rule always "recurses" backward and its condition "recurses" forward, am I correct? Also, what makes the algorithm append "recurse" backward? Is it append([],L,L)? Or does it always "recurse" backward after it reaches the base case?

The confusing thing is that simpler prolog recursion only "recurses" forward. If I am not mistaken ancestor(E,F) only "recurses" forward.

Comment: What is `ancestor/2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the third argument, X, here. It starts with a capital letter, so it is a variable. Prolog needs to find a value for this variable.

Everytime`append([H|T], L2, [H|L3])`is called, it calls`append(T, L2, L3)`.

When`append(T, L2, L3)`gets called, Prolog will first check if it fits`append([], L, L)`because that is the first clause of the program.

If it doesn't fit, Prolog will move on to the second clause:`append([H|T],L2,[H|L3])`.

It fits if the first argument is the empty list:`[]`. This happens if all the elements (letters in this case) have been removed. The clause will return the second argument L as the third argument. From start to finish, the second argument stays`[1,2,3]`all the time. It is only there for this moment.

The empty list`[]`is the base case: the recursion will not go deeper from there, because the clause doesn't have a body that calls`append`again. This is the point at which the first element for the result (third argument) is found: L which is`[1, 2, 3]`. This result is given back as L3 to the`append`that called it, which is gonna combine that with its H:`[H|L3]`which is`[c, 1, 2, 3]`. This in turn is given back to the`append`which called that one. This giving-back of results continues until the original, first-called append gets its result. Then Prolog prints it out.

In the trace you can see variables like`_G518`. In the first three lines the base case hasn't been reached yet, so the third argument can't be filled in (H is known but L3 isn't).